# Move constructor comment not getting printed

Tags: c++11, move-constructor

I have a small program like below:

```
    class boovector{
    private: int size;
            char *arr;
    public:
            boovector(){size=1;arr=new char[size];cout<<" boovector default constructor called"<<endl;}
            boovector(boovector &b)
            {
                cout<<"boovector copyconstructor called"<<endl;
                size = b.size;
                arr =  new char[size];
                strncpy(arr,b.arr,size);
            }
            boovector(boovector &&b)
            {
                cout<<"boovector move assignment operator called"<<endl;
                size =b.size;
                arr = b.arr;
                b.arr = nullptr;
            }
            ~boovector()
            {
                delete []arr;
            }

    };
    boovector createboovector()
    {
        boovector v;
        return v;
    }
    void foo(boovector v)
    {

    }
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        boovector vet = createboovector();
        foo(vet);
        foo(createboovector());
        return 0;
    }
```

### Output

```
boovector default constructor called
boovector copyconstructor called
boovector default constructor called
```

I was hoping to see ***"boovector move assignment operator called"*** in the output.

If I comment **move constructor "boovector(boovector &&b)"**, i get compiler error

```
  invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'boovector&' from an 
  rvalue of type 'boovector'
```

I want to understand the logic behind the move constructor not being called.

Comment: You're in a situation where declaring a copy constructor means you cannot move, but having a move constructor allows it to compile, but the compiler elides a copy/move as an optimization :-)

Comment: @AndyG, so do you mean there is a problem with the compiler? and I should shift to some other compiler?

Comment: No of course not. The compiler is doing you a favor.  Read up on [copy elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision). You can disable it in gcc with [-fno-elide-constructors](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html)

Comment: I don't see how that error message could be produced by the code you've shown. That code doesn't have a non-const `boovector&` reference anywhere. It's likely that the code you actually compile differs from the code you show.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, you are right, i accidentally made "const boovector&".

Answer (score -1):

In my case on MSVC 2017 Community Edition the produced output is:

```
 boovector default constructor called
boovector move assignment operator called
boovector copyconstructor called
 boovector default constructor called
boovector move assignment operator called
```

So it works as expected.